# Update Wordpress Post Date Automatically with Cron

Tags: wordpress, cron

I'm looking to take a particular category of posts on my wordpress site and update the publish date to the current date every 7 days. I've been given this code by someone who did so on their site. But, it's for every post. I want it only to be for a particular category.

```
add_action( 'update_post_test', 'update_post_test2' );function update_post_test2(){
$time = current_time('mysql');
$my_posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',  
    'fields' => 'ids', 
    ) 
);
foreach ( $my_posts as $my_post ):
    wp_update_post(
    array (
        'ID'            => $my_post,
        'post_date'     => $time,
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time )
    )
    );
endforeach;}
```

This is in my functions.php file, and then I'd simply add a hook in WP Ctrontrol to run update_post_test every week.

Not much of a coder. How would I get WP to update only those in a particular category.

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/ `Category` is one of the parameters `get_posts` takes inside of the argument array.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you